# Disable mouseClick on a part of the Screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to disable mouseClick in all my website Except a div in the middle.
But I don't know how to do this, maybe you do.

Comment: Your question is very broad. See [http://www.wikihow.com/Ask-a-Question-on-Stack-Overflow](http://www.wikihow.com/Ask-a-Question-on-Stack-Overflow)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add event handler to the `div` with [`addEventHandler`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener). Inside the handler you need to use [`event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) for the default behavior of the event to be cancelled and [`event.stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) to stop the event from bubbling up to parent elements. In the example below if you click around the red square, it will print 'clicked'. If you click inside the square, nothing happens:

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  console.log("clicked");
});

document.getElementById('disabled-mouse').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
#disabled-mouse {
  margin: 20px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="disabled-mouse">
  </div>
</div>
```

This only cancels the left mouse button click. If you need to cancel other events, you need to do the same for them. Check out the the list of mouse events: [Mouse Events](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp)

Comment: Thanks its exactly thats !!

Comment: @Blinkix please accept this answer if it solved your problem

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question right, You just need to use `event.stopPropagation();`

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/awyru3LL/

Good Luck

Comment: no sorry that not really that but I'm good thanks !